# rMBP Late 2013 Facetime HD Camera Not Working

Tags: macbook-pro, facetime

I have my rMBP since the end of December. When I got it, i needed to update the OS X to 10.9.1. I don't recall if i tried the FaceTime HD Camera later or before the system update, but i'm sure it was working back then.

Now it doesn't work. At least it isn't stable. Some time it works, but very little times. When i turn up the PhotoBooth or any other software (Skype, Messages), the greenlight starts to blink repeatedly and that's about it. I can't see nothing besides black image.

I've been reading in questions simillar to mine it this forum and others, but it seems people with a problem similiar to mine only happened in OS X 10.8.4.

I read in a post ( https://discussions.apple.com/message/24030755#24030755 ) that updating the AppleCamera.plugin, located at **/Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/** would do the trick. I've tried that, but with no results.

I've also performed a hardware diagnostics test. Didn't have any warning or error. Seems the hardware (the webcam in this case), is running just
fine. If anyone is interesting to perform the same test: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5781

Comment: Apparently I was able to solve the problem. The only thing i do was to uninstall Skype. It seems to have solved. I'm not sure if this happen cause i had installed the Skype through brew cask and therefore I probably didn't have the most recent version of Skype.

Comment: Post that as an answer for now.

Answer (score 1):

Skype is known to cause this issue. Update or uninstall that (or install a clean OS X on to an external drive to test this out).